# Clicking JavaScript in Ruby/Watir

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, webdriver

Is there ANY way to click a JavaScript link using the Watir webdriver? I've looked around for hours and nothing has helped me.

Here's what the link looks like: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="double_your_btc_link2" class="bold">MULTIPLY YOUR BTC</a>`
I've tried using `browser.link(:id, "double_your_btc_link2").click` and a bunch of other stuff including Xpath (it kept saying it couldn't follow the path) and nothing works. Is it even possible?

If you need the page, [here it is.](http://freebitco.in/?r=1477)

Comment: Where on the page is that link? I do not see it when I go to that page.

Comment: Don't link to the page, include the relevant part of the page in your question. If (when) the link breaks, the question won't have the needed information to make it usable for future people asking the same question. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: @theTinMan, right, that's why I gave the link code. The page was for if you needed more than that.

Comment: @JustinKo, you need to be logged in. Since the entire site is only one page you can probably find it in the source without logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to waste your time, guys. I just used Firefox instead of Chrome and it worked fine. This isn't even the first time I've had a problem with accessing JavaScript elements in Chrome...thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That should have been:

```
browser.link(:id => "double_your_btc_link2").click
```

Comment: No, still no luck with that. UnknownObjectException, unable to find element.

Comment: Also, is there really any difference between a regular and fat comma? I've been using regular commas the whole time and everything's been working fine.